# TimePicker Android

Tags: android

I am making an simple alarm clock in android, and I want to set the alarm in any time i want but i have no idea how can i do that.
I have an layout where I have timepicker and now from this line of code alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), sender);
     I wanna make my own time which i choosed from the layout from timepicker.
I have referenced timepicker

```
TimePicker addtime;
ddtime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.addtime);
```

How to get actually the value time which are in the timepicker??

Comment: or can i simpy do manyally the hour and minute where the alarm should come and how can i do this????

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to save the data that you want in some variables to use later.
Android has the TimePickerDialog and DatePickerDialog that you can use:

```
// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

 // the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

> Do not forget that if you want to use the two dialogs you will need to have a different id for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a TimePickerDialog.

Needs a listener defined in your class:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
            mHour = hour;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

In onCreate():

```
    Button timeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_entry_button);
    timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
```

In onCreateDialog():

```
    switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeListener, mHour, mMinute, true);

    }
```

Where updateDisplay() is a method in your class that will be called when the user has selected a time.

Comment: No, I just simply want to get the value of TimePicker nothing else, and I am making the alarm to notify each 5 second how can I make it in  desire time??

Comment: You can skip the dialog part and add a TimePicker widget to your view, the TimePicker widget supports an OnTimeChangedListener.  The problem is this fires off whenever the widget changes, it's difficult to know when the change is the final change.  You could also add a separate "Set Alarm" button and call mTimePicker.getCurrentHour() and mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute() when the user selects the button.  Unfortunately whether you use the widget or the dialog it only supports hours and minutes, not seconds..

Answer (score 0):

the code looks fine you just need to implement your necessary code in the onTimeSet() method as given above; one general example when you want to get the string timeString and then to set that string to a button is given below  -

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
         public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
           updateTime(hour, minute);
        }
    };

public void updateTime(int hour, int minute) {
        String timeString =  new StringBuilder().append(String.valueOf(hour))
                    .append(":").append(String.valueOf(minute)).ToString();
        btnEventTimeFrom.setText(timeString);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create time picker on runtime like this

```
TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(this);
               picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected:"+timePicker.getHour()+" \nMIN:"+timePicker.getMinute(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
                   }
               });
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CarDetailsActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(picker);
                dialog.show();
```

moreover you can create and add buttons to the layout also you can create xml file and can Use for Dialog like this

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(yourActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
    //find buttons if your layout contains and you can set on Click listerns on them like this
    Button buttonOK = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(lister->{
    //your code
    };
//getting time picker from xml
TimePicker tp = dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker_id);
//use your desired operations
```

Answer (score 0):

try this I did this for my current Project

time_picker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_6dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TimePicker
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:id="@+id/picker"
            style="@style/TimePickerStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <View
            android:background="@color/flat_blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cancle"

                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="@color/light_red"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/okay"

                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="@color/flat_blue"
                    android:text="Okay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

use this method to inflate and use

```
private void pickTime(){
        class CustomTime{
            private String hours,minutes;

            public CustomTime() {
            }
            //for my desire
            @NonNull
            @Contract(pure = true)
            String getFormattedTime(){
                return hours+":"+minutes+":00";
            }

            public CustomTime(String hours, String minutes) {
                this.hours = hours;
                this.minutes = minutes;
            }

            public String getHours() {
                return hours;
            }

            public String getMinutes() {
                return minutes;
            }



            public void setHours(String hours) {
                this.hours = hours;
            }

            public void setMinutes(String minutes) {
                this.minutes = minutes;
            }

        }
        String h,m;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        h = dateFormat.format(new Date()).split(":")[0];
        m = dateFormat.format(new Date()).split(":")[1];
        CustomTime time=new CustomTime(h,m);

        Dialog dialog = Utilities.showDialogWithCustomView(CarDetailsActivity.this,R.layout.time_picker);
        TimePicker picker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.picker);
        picker.setOnTimeChangedListener((timePicker, i, i1) -> {
            time.setHours(timePicker.getHour()+"");
            time.setMinutes(timePicker.getMinute()+"");
            if(time.getMinutes().length()==1){
                time.setMinutes("0"+time.getMinutes());
            }
            if(time.getHours().length()==1){
                time.setHours("0"+time.getHours());
            }

        });
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancle).setOnClickListener(listener -> dialog.dismiss());

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.okay).setOnClickListener(listener->{
            fromDate = fromDate + " "+time.getFormattedTime();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),fromDate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            moveToPayment();
            dialog.dismiss();
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
```

code for showDialogWithCustomView(Activity activity, @LayoutRes int layout)

```
 public static Dialog showDialogWithCustomView(Activity activity, @LayoutRes int layout) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(layout);
        return dialog;
    }
```