# How to open the "new alarm" dialog box

Tags: android, android-intent, clock, alarm

So what I'm trying to do is when I press a "Add new alarm" button, the dialog box from the stock Android clock feature opens up. I'm trying to see if there's a way to open that default dialog box, or if I need to make my own from scratch.

I've used code to set a new alarm, i.e.:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm"); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 10); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30); 
startActivity(i);
```

But I'm looking to see if I can access that window specifically.

Thanks.

Comment: **"...the dialog box from the stock Android clock feature opens up."** - No, this isn't possible. The closest you can get is to use the `TimePicker` class as mentioned by verybadalloc in his answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TimePicker Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320979/timepicker-android)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) dialog? In this case, try the TimePickerDialog, as explained here: [TimePicker Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320979/timepicker-android)